# Replacing actual numbers (1,2,3, etc) with a written number (one two three)

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I've been working on a problem and I have come across a small snag. I need to replace an actual number in a sentence with a written number.

An example:

> Stack overflow is the number **1** place for programming help

needs to become

> Stack overflow is the number **one** place for programming help

Also, this only needs to be done for numbers 0-9. Thanks for the help, any guidance or being pointed towards the correct apis would be appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far?  We're not here to do homework for people (and I say that as a former lab aide who taught a lab where what you ask was the assignment).  However, we're happy to help you debug something you've already tried.

Comment: I don't think there is an API for this. Then, you need to do it by hand: replace 1 by one, 2 by two, etc.

Comment: Use an `enum` for your digits.

Comment: Simply use a map, use regex replace operation based on keyset of the map.

Comment: What is the maximum number you need to support?

Comment: @sildoreth it needs to go to 9, however I think i have it covered now

Comment: I'm a fan of all of the people who downvote a legitimate question and answer just because it doesn't fit their needs rather than the needs of the OP... yes... that was sarcasm.  Thank you X Tech for the post and I'm glad that you found a solution that works for you and your problem.  To those who what to generalize the problem, great, but don't downvote just because the answers didn't take **your** problem into account... only the OP should do that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out "I think" but maybe you can verify.

so basically it is going to loop through a sentence looking through it for numbers. Im thinking a series of for loops such as

```
 for (int i=0; i < strToWork.length(); i++)
       {
           if (strToWork.charAt(i) == '1')
             {
                strToWork.replace(i,i+1,"one")
                  }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String`'s replaceAll(String,String) method.  Below is an example:

```
String myString = "This is 1 great tool for 3 people to use!";
System.out.println(myString.replaceAll("1", "one").replaceAll("2", "two"));
```

If you really want to, you can use `Pattern`, since the first argument of replaceAll is a regex anyway..

Comment: This does not handle the case of: "Stack overflow is the number 11 place for programming help". The OP asked for handling only 0-9.

Comment: `replaceAll` uses regular expressions. Just use `replace` for this.

Comment: @Jason The OP doesn't care about 11.  In fact 11 can just say 'oneone', by how I read the OP.  Sure, I could have used complex methods like some of the answers, but that would have been overkill.  As it stands, I purposefully used replaceAll vice replace (and stated it uses a regex) because I wanted to get the OP thinking about how they could maybe use a regex instead (Pattern!) and then maybe a String switch using the mechanisms of Pattern (find(), start(), and end()) to maybe do it better than .replace(blah,blah).replace(blach,blach), etc.

Comment: @DavidConrad I put that in so that I could put in the teaser about Pattern, hoping that the OP would look into the cool ways (s)he could use it for things like this in the future.